# How to upload an Android file to S3 bucket with public permission

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, awss3transferutility

I keep trying to upload a file to an s3 bucket. But the file is never public for viewing. I have to manually make the files/folder in the bucket public (for every upload) for it to be view able.

Is there a way to upload an Android file (bitmap) with the default permission to be public for viewing during. I would prefer to do this programmatically, if possible. I've checked the s3 docs, couldn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make all objects in your bucket public by default, view the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176926/how-to-make-all-objects-in-aws-s3-bucket-public-by-default) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35380872/how-to-set-acl-for-an-object-while-uploading-it-to-amazon-s3).

To specify public access for each file when you are uploading them via Android, set the ACL on the `PutObjectRequest` like this:

```
PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest()
    .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead)
```

---

It doesn't look like you can set the ACL in one step with `TransferUtility` at this time: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/63

So after uploading the file via `TransferUtility` you would need to do the following:

```
s3client.setObjectAcl(bucketName, keyName, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
```

Comment: Could you edit your code and include an example of setting the ACL when uploading via transfer utility service?

Comment: I also having same problem while i use putObjectRequest than my device getting freeze.Please help me if anyone have solution.for further detail please see my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37923689/device-is-freez-while-set-acl-permission-of-s3-bucket).

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is very easy for those guys, who is using **TransferUtility**,
use below method for uploading any file for **public readable** form using TransferUtility in android,

```
transferUtility.upload(String bucketName,String key,File file,CannedAccessControlList cannedAcl)
```

**Example:**

```
transferUtility.upload("MY_BUCKET_NAME","FileName",your_file,CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
```

Comment: Wrong 4th argument found. Required ObjectMetaData as 4th argument.

Comment: Hello @HardikJoshi, i am using following library in my project, - compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.+'
   - compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.+'
   - compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.+'

and there are four methods in the TransferUtility class for uploading file, and if you are using ObjectMetadata also as a parameter you can pass "new ObjectMetadata()" in the fourth parameter.

Comment: Ok. after update library to latest version, it works. Thanks bro!